# How to read batch file and retrieve specific data in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the below code. What I want, is to read from a txt with the below format

e.g.

```
localhost   127.0.0.1   22
router  192.168.1.1 22
ESXi    192.168.1.95    22
XPEnology   192.168.1.48    22
Nagios  192.168.1.97 22
Centos  192.168.1.96    22
localhost   127.0.0.1   21
```

and I want retrieve the second "column" and third "column" in order to proceed with the connectivity test.

but i get the error

```
    s.connect((IP, PORT))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

any help would be appreciate.

Thank you all

```
    while True:
        f = input('Type the File Name/Path:')
        if f == '': break
        try:
            with open(f, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                for check in f:
                    check = check.split('\t')
#                    HOSTNAME = check[0]
                    IP = check[1]
                    PORT = check[2]
                    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                    s.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
                    s.connect(IP, PORT))
                    f = open("output.txt", "a")
            #           print("[%s] Connection established" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), file=f)
                    print('IP:', IP, ',' 'PORT:', PORT, ',' "Connection established", file=f)
            #            print(IP)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    f.close()
                    s.close()
                    break
        except IOError:
                f = open("output.txt", "a")
                print('IP:', IP,',' 'PORT:', PORT,',' "Cannot Connect", file=f)
                f.close()
                break

#                   connections.append((HOSTNAME, IP, PORT))
#            for v in connections:
#               print(v)

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("\n")
            print('The file {} does not exist'.format(f))
            input('Press ENTER to continue...')
            print("\n")
            break
```

Comment: From `socket` documentation _"A pair (host, port) is used for the AF_INET address family, where host is a string representing either a hostname in Internet domain notation like 'daring.cwi.nl' or an IPv4 address like '100.50.200.5', and **port is an integer**."_ (emphasis is mine).

Comment: so should be  port = int(check[2])   ???

Comment: solved. it is running now. thank you